# Classic ASP session state in IIS 8

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I am stuck on one issue and I need your help badly.

I have an ASP site configured to run on IIS 8. Now, due to server load, IIS is not responding after a while and i need to reset IIS to start the site again.

Basically, I am from an ASP.Net environment. So here in ASP, I am having a problem applying the proper configuration. One thing I would like to accomplish here is to increase the number of worker process for the site in IIS, but I am afraid that if I do that then there may be a session issue. As you know, ASP sites do not have sessionstates and its default will be of InProc.

However, I read on MSDN about the keepSessionIdSecure property. This indicates that the session is stored on the Client in cookies. Does this mean that i can safely increase the number of worker process?

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.  This is the production server, and I would not like to take any chances here.

Comment: ist that really asp-classic? or ASP.NET?

Comment: @ulluoink its a classic ASP. Sorry i should be more specific there

Comment: @user867198 - I see that you have no answers for this question.  Have you been able to resolve this issue?